# How to solve UnimplementedError on tensorflow model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

```
    X_data = transformed_df["content"].str.lower()
    y_data = emotions_df

    topLayerModel = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
    topLayerModel.add(Dense(256, input_shape=(512,), activation='relu'))
    topLayerModel.add(Dense(256, input_shape=(256,), activation='relu'))
    topLayerModel.add(Dropout(0.5))
    topLayerModel.add(Dense(128, input_shape=(256,), activation='relu'))
    topLayerModel.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))  
    model.compile(optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(), metrics = ["accuracy"], loss =                 
    "categorical_crossentropy"),

    model.fit(X_data, y_data, epochs = 5)
```

My error can be found on model.fit but i dont know how to solve the transform_df at all. how do i convert string to float? I really do hope someone can help me thank you!!

```
    Epoch 1/5
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    UnimplementedError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-103-47abb3d08a2f> in <module>()
         29 model.compile(optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(), metrics = ["accuracy"], loss =         
    "categorical_crossentropy"),
         30 
    ---> 31 model.fit(X_data, y_data, epochs = 5)
         32 
         33 
    
    
    8 frames
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in                 
    quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
         58     ctx.ensure_initialized()
         59     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
    ---> 60                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
         61   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
         62     if name is not None:
    
    UnimplementedError:  Cast string to float is not supported
         [[node sequential_4/dense_16/Cast (defined at <ipython-input-103-47abb3d08a2f>:31) ]]                 
    [Op:__inference_train_function_13983]
    
    Function call stack:
    train_function
```

help please :(

Comment: X_data is string type

Answer (score 0):

Happened with me when I wanted to read *.csv* file and I read it and converted it to *str*, but it was solved when I let in as it's **no conversion**

```
df = pd.read_csv("sqli.csv.csv", engine="python")
#df = df.astype(str)  <<-- here the reason of code exception
```

So, for you try to remove *str* from *X_data*

```
X_data = transformed_df["content"].lower()
```

if ***content*** contain *symbols* and you need to let it as it's, remove also `lower()`

```
X_data = transformed_df["content"]
```